# Ruby on rails HTTP request issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-4, getjson

I am an newbie to Ruby on Rails. I have a url which points to a JSON output. When I ran the URL directly like http://user:pass@myurl.com/json, I am getting the response without any authendication. However http://myurl.com/json requires a username and password through a standard apache pop up authentication box. I have tried to access this URL from my rails controller like the following:

```
result = JSON.parse(open("http://user:pass@myurl.com/json").read)
```

When I try to do, I just get an error which says ArgumentError, userinfo not supported. [RFC3986]

Also I have tried the below one. I am getting a 401-Unauthorized error

```
open("http://...", :http_basic_authentication=>[user, password])
```

How can I make a request that works in this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What help you need, indeed?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html

Comment: @ArslanAli How can I make my request to work in this case?

Comment: @maxcal The target page needs an authentication. But I am not sure how to pass that in

Comment: `open("http://myurl.com/json", :http_basic_authentication=>[ "user", "pass"] )` ,    it work for me, maybe you should give us more detail

Comment: @ShallmentMo I used your code. I am getting this error `open_http': 401 Unauthorized

Comment: @RAHULDEV , at least it doesn't says userinfo not supported. Did you use the correct username and password?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Basic+Authentication) (or some [other HTTP client](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients)).

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI('http://myurl.com/json')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new( uri )
req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'
res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
result = JSON.parse(res.body)
puts result
```

Comment: That fixed the Auth issue. But now I am getting `initialize': undefined method `empty?' Please advice.

Comment: You are most likely calling `.empty?` on a variable which is nil. Look at the stack trace and find where the error is being raised.

Comment: Can you explain bit more about this